# List view not working in android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make an app of notifications for my college project.

I am trying to create a Customized Adapter for a listview , but the activity containing the ListView does not show anything. I think I have done something wrong in the getView() method in CustomAdapter.java.

CustomAdapter class is used to created the child views for the the listview. listviechild.xml defines the layout for single row in the listview tith xml file - listactivity.xml

```
    package com.example.client_nic;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public Context context =null;
        public ArrayList<String> nam = null;
        public ArrayList<String> date= null;
        public ArrayList<String> time = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater =null;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> nam,
                ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> time) {
            super();
            nam = new ArrayList<String>();
            date = new ArrayList<String>();
            time = new ArrayList<String>();

            this.context = context;
            this.nam = nam;
            this.date = date;
            this.time = time;

            inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return nam.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("name",nam.get(pos));
            Log.e("date",date.get(pos));
            Log.e("time", time.get(pos));

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewchild, arg2,false);
            if(view.isActivated()){
                Toast.makeText(context, "yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            TextView nametv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView datetv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView timetv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            nametv.setText(nam.get(pos));
            datetv.setText(date.get(pos));
            timetv.setText(time.get(pos));
            return view;
        }

    }






listviewchild.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:height="30dp" />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:height="20dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:height="20dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"

      />

</RelativeLayout>

listactivity.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Link your activity that uses this adapter and attaches to the listview. I have a suspicion of a missing setAdapter call or empty data being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code I think that the instance varibles of class CustomAdapter (ArrayList s) nam, date and time are not getting filled with the contents of the corresponding ArrayList passed to the constructor due to which the Activity containing ListView is displaying nothing.
Replace the constructor with the following code

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> nam,
            ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> time) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.nam.addAll(nam);
        this.date.addAll(date); 
        this.time.addAll(time);

        inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

package com.example.client_nic;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Context context =null;
    public ArrayList<String> nam = null;
    public ArrayList<String> date = null;
    public ArrayList<String> time = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> nam,
            ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> time) {
        nam = new ArrayList<String>();
        date = new ArrayList<String>();
        time = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.context = context;
        this.nam = nam;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return nam.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("name",nam.get(pos));
        Log.e("date",date.get(pos));
        Log.e("time", time.get(pos));

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewchild, arg2, false);
        if(view.isActivated()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        TextView nametv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView datetv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView timetv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        nametv.setText(nam.get(pos));
        datetv.setText(date.get(pos));
        timetv.setText(time.get(pos));
        return view;
    }

}
```

This should properly inflate your views and work. If there are other problems, you may be passing empty data to to the Adapter.

***Couple of side notes***

1) You are passing three ArrayLists to fill the data for your ListView. Why not just pass a single array list with custom Java objects? The fields for the java objects would be name, data, time.

i.e:

```
public class MyObject{
    public String name;
    public String date;
    public String time;

    MyObject(String name, String date, String time){
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    //define getters and setters...
}
```

and:

```
 public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyObject> objs) {
     ...
     ...
 }
```

2) You are inflating the view each time. Instead, use the [ViewHolder Pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) to hold the views data rather than re-drawing this and looking up resources each time in your application. Android makes use of recycling views so you want to maximize on this and save resources and reduce delays from loading views each time (lots of overhead!). I will not provide an example on this for you, but look up that link to find out how to do this yourself!

Comment: May I ask why you are not passing the ViewGroup to the LayoutInflater? I know the call `inflate(R.resource, null)` is equal to `inflate(R.resource, null, false)` but looking at the source of the inflate method it needs the ViewGroup to get the parent layout parameters otherwise it will create generated parameters from the attributeset. Im a bit rusty on Android but with this the created view would match the parent which is the phone's dimensions, right?

Comment: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(id, null) will cause the height to wrap and the width to match parent, so indeed we might not want that here. Instead, we should use LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(id, parent, false); this in fact takes the layout params from layout defined under id and applies those to the height and width. Fixed in edit. Only change he needs in the inflater's instantiation

Comment: It is interesting how the code now is identical to OP's code, only getting the inflater is done in nicer way. (Basically the same as the OP does, but more read friendly, again looked up the source :P). However your extra notes are extremely helpful! I am wondering though if this code fixes the issue the OP is having.

Comment: Should work (I have done this before!).. the only thing that would be an issue is improper use of the adapter not being set (i.e setAdapter) or empty data being passed

Comment: I am agreeing with you and wondering if the OP even attached the adapter to the ListView, it is a very silly mistake but it does happen (I can throw in some of my own experience there xD)